# Compiling a autoit script via cmd/batch not working with #include

Tags: batch-file, compiler-construction, autoit

I have this script I made with some help from MC ND and it works but if I have `#include <Constants.au3>` in the autoit file it will throw a error. It works if the `#include` isn't there. If I compile it using the autoit its self then it compile ok. This is my code:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 
    for %%a in ("%cd%\*.au3") do (
        Aut2exe.exe /in "%%~fa" /out "%%~dpna.exe" /icon "%%~dpa\icon.ico" /x86 /comp 4
    )
    endlocal
xcopy *.exe Compile\*.exe
del /f *.exe
xcopy /D /I /V /Y Compile\Aut2exe.exe
del /f Compile\Aut2exe.exe
```

Thanks if any one can help.

Comment: Where is the `constants.au3` file located?

Comment: @MCND It is located in this directory: `G:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Include`.

Comment: And, the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AutoIt v3\AutoIt\Include` are ...?

Comment: @MCND This registry entry isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AutoIt Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/include.htm)

> The search order used by AutoIt depends on which form of #include you
>   use. The tables below show the order directories are searched using
>   both forms.
>
> Using #include <>
>
> Standard library
>
> ```
> The path of the currently running interpreter with "\Include" appended is 
> searched.
> ```
>
> User-defined libraries
>
> ```
> The registry value mentioned above is read and each directory is searched 
> in the order they appear in.
> ```
>
> Script directory
>
> ```
> The directory of the currently executing script.
> ```
>
> Aut2Exe uses the same algorithm as AutoIt3.exe with the only difference being
>   it looks for the Include sub-directory as being in a sibling directory to 
>   itself (..\Include)

From your posted code, it "seems" you have copied the `aut2exe` to the scripts folders, but the file you are referencing is in the standard libraries folder and, according to documentation, it will not be found.

You can

- Copy the `constants.au3` to the same folder that holds the scripts
- Configure the registry entry to point to the folder holding the include file
- Call the `aut2exe` file from its folder in standard distribution of autoit so it can find the include folder
- Change the `#include` directive to `#include "path\filename"` to directly point to the include file